# importing tkinter, or root.tkinter doesnt work for me

Tags: python, tkinter

I recently picked up learning Python 3, so far I've been loving it!

I'm trying to create a harry potter story game as a project, for this I'm learning how to use Tkinter.

I've done some research on how to import it but nothing seems to work.

I don't know what part of it is wrong, so I added the entire code

I've looked in a lot of places and asked some friends, but none of the possible solutions work for me.

```
from tkinter import * as tk
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
#Initialize main window
window = tkinter.Tk()
#Size window properly
window.minsize (1280, 720)
#Now to give your window a title
window.title ("HogWarts Express")
#Add an Icon
root.iconbitmap("/Users/name/Desktop/The_Hogwarts_Experience/Harry_Potter_Story_Game/icon.ico")
tk.call("wm", "iconphoto", )
root.iconphoto

#Place Label
label = tkinter.Label (window, text="Continue")

#Place the label and specific coordinates
label.place (x=600, y=330)

#Initialize the counter
counter = 0

#Function to find the screen dimesions & calculate the center and set geometry
def center_window(w=600, h=700):
    # Call all pending idle tasks - carry out geometry management and redraw widgets.
    win.update_idletasks()
    # Get width and height of the screen
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
    # Calculate x, y
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    # Set geometry
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))



#Define button press function
def press():
    #use global counter variable.
    global counter
    #count each button's press
    counter = counter + 1
    #set Label
    label.config(text=f"Button clicked: {counter} times")

#Place button on the window
button = tkinter.Button (window, text="Click Me", command=press)

#place at coordinates
button.place(x=10, y=40)

#show the window
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I followed a youtube tutorial for this code, so it has nothing to do with Harry Potter yet. I'm just experimenting with stuff.

Comment: `from tkinter import * as tk`: this is incorrect. Remove it. If after that you still have problems, add the traceback to the question. There are several problems not related to import in your code, E.g. you write `tkinter.Label` but the module tkinter does not exist. You _named it_ as `tk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got severel issues in this code, solved below:

```
#from tkinter import * as tk #this is wrong in different ways, dont do that
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
#window = tkinter.Tk() # you alreade have tk.Tk()
root.minsize(1280, 720) #use root since root = tk.Tk()
root.title("HogWarts Express")# dont use space here
root.iconbitmap("/Users/name/Desktop/The_Hogwarts_Experience/Harry_Potter_Story_Game/icon.ico")
#tk.call("wm", "iconphoto", ) 
#root.iconphoto

label = tk.Label(root, text="Continue") #imported as tk so use tk
label.place(x=600, y=330)

counter = 0

def center_window(w=600, h=700):
    root.update_idletasks() #root is the window
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))


def press():
    global counter
    counter = counter + 1
    label.config(text=f"Button clicked: {counter} times")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=press) #root is the window/master
button.place(x=10, y=40)

root.mainloop()
```

### I highly recommand you to follow ONE tutorial not many, its confusing. I have started with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuoSKkSEhQg&list=PL6lxxT7IdTxGoHfouzEK-dFcwr_QClME_).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm just so overwhelmed by all the available information on Python I didn't know where to start. I appreciate the link and correction! Thank you for that!

Comment: @Komas I had the same trouble, understanding one by one is key. Please note [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: it is done! That playlist is extremely useful! Thank you lots and lots!